# Excel: want to add and count cell values of column A if it found specific criteria in column B

Tags: excel

I have 2columns B & C. Column C having values which i want to count and sum() but if it found specific value in column B. e.g:- how many/much "P" values in column C against "Cotton" value in column B.

B        C

1. ABC     P
2. ABC     P
3. XYZ   0.50

Comment: have you tried `countif` ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, this may be a job for COUNTIFS. Countifs allows you to provide multiple ranges and multiple criteria to count:

```
=COUNTIFS(B1:B3,"Cotton",C1:C3,"P")
```

Should return the number of Cottons and P on the same row.

There is also a comparable SUMIFS function that allows you to do the same thing but instead of counting it sums the values in the provided range.

Comment: also want to get sumup as same way

Comment: The SUMIFS function works similarly. From your example, let's say you also have a column D with values to sum.

`=SUMIFS(D1:D3, B1:B3, "Cotton, C1:C3, "P")`